# VBA ActiveDocument Concerns / Alternatives?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using VBA in access to open up a protected word template, fill in the data, and then re-protect it.... this way, if the database system goes down, the word template can still be used manually in its protected state.

I have just started using VBA and in this line:

```
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
End If
```

I'm concerned that whilst running the code in access, that if the user opens up another word document and makes it the focus, that it will occidentally get protected instead of the other. How do I keep active focus on the document I'm writing to... or do I need to reference my document somehow using WordApp.protect (or something similar that works)

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim strDatabasePath As String
Dim strTemplatePath As String
Dim strTemplate As String
Dim strJobTitle As String
Dim strFile As String

strFile1 = "testcoc.dotx"
strFile2 = "testcoc-private.dotx"
strDatabasePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
strTemplatePath = "\templates\"
strTemplate = strDatabasePath & strTemplatePath & strFile2


On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo ErrHandler


WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=strTemplate, NewTemplate:=True


'strJobTitle = DLookup("JobTitle", "Job", "JobNum = " & [JobType])
strJobTitle = DLookup("JobTitle", "Job", "JobNum = 'J0456'")

With WordApp.Selection

'Unprotect the file
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
End If

    .Goto what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bm_0_4"
    .TypeText strJobTitle


End With

'Reprotect the document.
'If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
    'ActiveDocument.Protect _
    'Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:=""
'End If


DoEvents
WordApp.Activate
Set WordApp = Nothing
Exit Sub


ErrHandler:
Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this but `WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=strTemplate, NewTemplate:=True` does return the new document. So I would do something like

```
Dim doc as Word.Document
Set doc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=strTemplate, NewTemplate:=True)
```

and reference `doc` throughout my code instead of `ActiveDocument`. It seems like doing that should get help you avoid the particular situation you're concerned about.

Comment: This is the way to go. I think people use ActiveDocument because that's what the macro recorder generates (and it doesn't know any better). Use your own *specific* object reference, returned by `WordApp.Documents.Add` or `WordApp.Documents.Open`.

Comment: I get an error of "type mismatch" on the set doc line, I dont understand because documents.add returns a document and Ive declared my dim var as document, so how can this be a type mismatch? am I just being daft because Ive just woken up?

Comment: I figured it out, I used  `word.document` as the type instead of `document` and now everything works!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @IanJackson I've updated the answer to help others