# VBA Access object code for DropDownList ContentControls

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am coding an Access database that will collect user input, then open a Word document and fill out various parts of the document.

The problem I am having is it will only work once for Drop Down Lists.  Not sure why or where to look to fix this one.  There are three types of items I am programmatically filling in.  The first is bookmarks, no problem with this.  Second is Content Control Checkboxes, these also work with no problems.  The third is Content Control Drop Down Lists, this is where the problem is.  First time I open the Access Database it works, but if I click the command button again, nothing (for Drop Downs).  The main problem is that it doesn't produce an error message, so I am not sure where to look.

I am guessing it has something to do with the objects I am creating to do the drop down updates?  any help would be great:

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim strTemplateLocation As String
Dim dir As String
Dim path As String
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

path = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\"))
strTemplateLocation = path & "UserDoc.docx"

On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateLocation, newtemplate:=False

With WordApp

'Working Bookmark   
  .Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="COMPANY": .Selection.TypeText [fac]

'Working checkbox
If Me.RD = True Then: .ActiveDocument.ContentControls(9).Checked = True

'Works ONCE drop down
 Dim objCC As ContentControl
 Dim objCE As ContentControlListEntry
 Dim ListSelection As String

 ListSelection = Me.System_Type.ListIndex + 2
 Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1): Set objCE = objCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(ListSelection): objCE.Select

End With
```

Should I be closing out the objCE and objCC at the end or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably your problem:

```
Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
```

It should be

```
Set objCC = .ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
```

But much better would be:

```
Set wDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=strTemplateLocation, newtemplate:=False)
```

and then always use `wDoc` instead of `WordApp.ActiveDocument`.

See here: [VBA ActiveDocument Concerns / Alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082705/vba-activedocument-concerns-alternatives)

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks a bunch.